# how to exit on press back button from a screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

I am using go_router and I want to exit my app from a subroute when the user presses the back button. for example, I have routes '/', '/a', '/b', '/a/1'. now I from the '/a/1' route I want to exit the app when the user presses the back button(based on some condition). please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your Page's Scaffold with **WillPopScope** Widget and add this invokeMethod  to **onWillPop**.

```
return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        await SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop');
        return false;
      },
      child: Scaffold(...),
   );
```

Comment: yes, WillPopScope worked for me. I solved this... just forgot to mention it. but there is a problem in your code maybe, I think it needs to  return `false`

Comment: yes, fixed it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

just wrap the `Scaffold` with `WillPopScope` and inside the `onWillPop` function use `SystemNavigator.pop()` with the return value `false`. but `SystemNavigator` does not work like `Navigator`. and according to Apple's Human Interface Guidelines forcefully exiting is not allowed. Unfortunately, your app will not be approved for the Apple Store.

```
WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () async {
    SystemNavigator.pop();
    return false;
  },
  child:...
}
```

Comment: WillPopScope doesnot work when  using go_router.

Comment: well, `WillPopScope` is now deprecated. use `PopScope`. and don't forget to use `canPop: false,`